# amazon advertising api v2 createCampaigns fail

Tags: c#, amazon-advertising-api

There was an error using Amazon's advertising API CreateCampaigns: {"code":"422","details":"The server understood your request but was unable to process one or more parameters.","requestId":"KJPAT6WACV2V4GVXV0A0"}

```
List<Model.CreatePortfoliosRequestModel> createPortfoliosRequestModels = new List<Model.CreatePortfoliosRequestModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Model.CreatePortfoliosRequestModel createPortfoliosRequestModel = new Model.CreatePortfoliosRequestModel();
    createPortfoliosRequestModel.Name = $"My Portfolio One15{i}1s1asdsfd";
    createPortfoliosRequestModel.State = Enum.StateEnum.Enabled;
    createPortfoliosRequestModel.Budget = new Model.BudgetModel() { Amount = 102 + i, StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10 + i), EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100 + i), Policy = "dateRange" };
    createPortfoliosRequestModels.Add(createPortfoliosRequestModel);
}
var createPortfoliosResponseModels = portfolioService.CreatePortfoliosAsync(createPortfoliosRequestModels).Result;
```

> {"code":"422","details":"The server understood your request but was
>   unable to process one or more
>   parameters.","requestId":"KJPAT6WACV2V4GVXV0A0"}

Comment: Please check the `createPortfolios example` section of [Amazon Advertising API documentation](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/portfolios). It looks like the expected value of `startDate` and `endDate` parameters is something like `20181201`. Does your code format the `startDate` and `endDate` parameters correctly when sending the request to `createPortfolios` endpoint?

Comment: Here I've done some special processing to serialize `startDate` and `endDate` into `yyyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Did you mean createCampaigns (like in the topic) or createPortfolios (like in the code example)?